# Displaying floating point variable as a hex integer screws up neighbouring integer

Tags: c, floating-point, hex, printf, format-specifiers

I have this simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
 unsigned int a = 0x120;
 float b = 1.2;
 printf("%X %X\n", b, a);
 return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be

```
some-value 120  (some-value will depend on the bit pattern of `float b` )
```

But I see

```
40000000 3FF33333
```

Why is the value of `a` getting screwed up? `%X` treats its arguments as `signed int` and hence it should have retrieved 4 bytes from the stack and printed the calue of `b` and then fetching the next 4 bytes print the value of `a` which is `0x120`

Comment: Don't lie to `printf()` and the like. Ever. If you promise it to give an `int`, give it an `int` or a `short` or a `char`. If you promise to give it a `long`, give it a `long`. Ditto for `long long`. If you promise to give it a floating-point value, give it a `float` or a `double`. If you promise it a long floating point value, give it a `long double`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, it's undefined behaviour to pass arguments to `printf` not matching the format specifiers.

Secondly, the `float` is promoted to `double` when passed to `printf`, so it's eight bytes instead of four. Which bytes get interpreted as the two `unsigned` values expected by the `printf` format depends on the order in which the arguments are pushed.

Comment: Why the automatic promotion to double when I've clearly defined it to be `float`?

Comment: @Stacker That's just the way varargs work. Floating-point types smaller than `double` get promoted to `double`. Integer types smaller than `int` get promoted to `int`.

Comment: @Stacker:  that's how floats work in C.  `float` vs. `double` is only a storage declaration.  Floating point values are "always" handled as doubles in computations.

Comment: @wallyk: floats are not always handled as doubles in computations.  However, they *are* always promoted to doubles when passed as arguments to a varargs function (this is one of the *default argument promotions*)

Comment: Thanks folks for the explanation. The same program on gcc-ubuntu gives me  `120 120`. Should I assume that its cos of undefined behavior? The way Daniel explained about how the variables are stacked doesn't seem to hold good in this case.

Comment: @Stacker: yes, it's undefined behavior; what actually happens will be dependent on the parameter passing conventions of the target platform, and you *will* see different behavior on different platforms.

Comment: @StephenCanon:  Yes, I know it is not strictly always true (that is the reason for the quotes).  But it is more true than not for a general answer.

Comment: @Stacker I suspect that gcc on Ubuntu passes the `float` in a floating point register, so the printf doesn't touch it because it doesn't look there.

Comment: @wallyk: I find it hard to agree with that assessment.  It's not true on any x86-64 or ARM platform with which I am familiar.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the bits of a stored float, use a union:

```
 float b = 1.2;
 union {
      float  f;
      int    i;
 } u;
 u.f = b;

 printf ("%x\n", u.i);
```

results (32-bit x86):

```
3f99999a
```