# float output format yields weird value

Tags: c, floating-point, format

*OK:*
I found that this is [a dupe question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436906/displaying-floating-point-variable-as-a-hex-integer-screws-up-neighbouring-integ)

For my answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047598/how-to-make-a-decimal-to-hexadecimal-converter-in-c/20048482#20048482), I tested what would happen  if I passed a float to `printf`, and have it printed out as a hexadecimal value.
The code I used was simply this:

```
int main()
{
    float i = 12.2;
    printf("%x == %f\n", i, i);
    return 0;
}
```

The result was somewhat surprizing, to say the least:

```
60000000 == 26815622268991053043690768862555225929794561970930945383754133458631904088629457662404735694345936594619420127195201411004744101710347755649498829446709248.000000
```

Now that couldn't be quite true, I do think. If I switch the order of the format string to `"%f == %x\n"`, the float shows up well (`12.200000`).
Now this intrigued me somewhat. So I did some more experimenting

```
printf("%f == %x == %f\n", i, i, i);
```

revealed to me that the `%f` format fails *after* the `%x` has been used. So I tried:

```
printf("%f == %x == %f\n", 12.2, i, 12.2);
```

Which had me scratching my noodle even more:

```
12.200000 == 60000000 == 190359837254612272720121546180914982603183590679420528733621571728996711854558612668142684377801318191569131534073063745617380878171517108433746379972393615159806611654135195336789983232.000000
```

And, before you ask:

```
printf("%f == %x == %f\n", 12.2f, i, 12.2f);
```

yields:

```
12.200000 == 60000000 == 26815622268991053043690768862555225929794561970930945383754133458631904088629457662404735694345936594619420127195201411004744101710347755649498829446709248.000000
```

When I print `printf("%f\n", i)` either before or after the statement(s) I posted above, the output is as I'd expect it to be.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: The compiler should have warned you that you are doing no good using the wrong conversion specifiers, at least if were told it to warn. Use option `-Wall` for gcc to do so.

Comment: @alk: I would've used `-Wall`, if I weren't using codepad... should've thought of that. sorry. I've voted to close this question, because I've already found a dupe

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate, and the answer given at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10436960/1424877 is better than any of the answers given on this page. :)  (The accepted answer on this page is 100% correct, of course, but it doesn't explain what happened on your particular machine to give the output you observed.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your program's behavior is **undefined**. Wrong conversion specifier invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Ok, I found a dupe, I'm ashamed to admit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436906/displaying-floating-point-variable-as-a-hex-integer-screws-up-neighbouring-integ

Answer (score 2):

The `%x` format is for integers, not floating point. To print a float in hex format, use `%a`. To print the raw bytes of a float (or other arbitrary object) in hex, which is what I'm guessing you really want, you have to use a union:

```
union {
  float f;
  unsigned int i;
} u;
u.f = 1.2;
printf("%x", u.i);
```

or `memcpy` the bytes from the float to an int and then printf the int.

Or you can cheat and use `*(int *)&some_float`